# Cannot access the data from a List(Of List)

Tags: vb.net, list, revit-api

I am working on a Revit Add-in and in that add-in I am trying to use a `List(Of List(Of Curve))`, however I'm having issue accessing the data from the sublists.

```
Dim ClosedCurveList As New List(Of List(Of Curve))
Dim ClosedCurve As new List (Of Curve)

For i=0 To FinalWallLines.Count-1
    If FinalWallLines(i+1).GetEndPoint(0).X = FinalWallLines(i).GetEndPoint(1).X And _
       FinalWallLines(i+1).GetEndPoint(0).Y = FinalWallLines(i).GetEndPoint(1).Y And _
       FinalWallLines(i+1).GetEndPoint(0).Z = FinalWallLines(i).GetEndPoint(1).Z Then

        ClosedCurve.Add(FinalWallLines(i))

    Else

        TaskDialog.Show("A",ClosedCurve.Count)
        ClosedCurveList.Add(ClosedCurve)
        TaskDialog.Show("B", ClosedCurveList(ClosedCurveList.Count-1).Count)
        ClosedCurve.Clear()

    End if
Next

TaskDialog.Show("C", ClosedCurveList.Count)

For i=0 To ClosedCurveList.Count-1
    TaskDialog.Show(i,ClosedCurveList(i).Count)
next
```

So when I run that code, the first `TaskDialog.Show("A",ClosedCurve.Count)` shows me that all of `ClosedCurve` are made of 4 curves, which makes sense as all my curves are forming rectangles.

My second `TaskDialog.Show("B", ClosedCurveList(ClosedCurveList.Count-1).Count)` also return 4 as the count for each of the sublists, as expected.

My third `TaskDialog.Show("C", ClosedCurveList.Count)` returns 23.

So from that, we can gather than `ClosedCurveList` is a list of 23 lists of 4 curves.

However, during my loop `For i=0 To ClosedCurveList.Count-1`, my `TaskDialog.Show(i,ClosedCurveList(i).Count)` returns 23 0s.

Would anyone know why I am not getting 23 4s as expected when trying to access the count of each of my sublists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ClosedCurve.Clear()` you should have `ClosedCurve = new List(Of Curve)`.

When you add it to `ClosedCurveList` you are not adding a copy. You are adding the reference to the object `CLosedCurve`.  And so, when you clear `ClosedCurve`, it also clears the one which was added in `ClosedCurveList` because they are references to the same object. By re-assigning a new `List(Of Curve)` to `ClosedCurve`, you will now have separate references, like you were originally expecting.